# find and replace whole line python

Tags: python, regex, file, replace

I have a file like this..

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
a b c invalid #seperated by tab
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I need to replace `a b c invalid` to `a b reviewed rd # separated by tab`
Basically any line that ends with invalid, I need to replace that line with `reviewed rd // separated by tab` but I have to keep the first and second words on that line (only replace 3rd and 4th).

I have started doing something like this, but this won't exactly do what I want.

```
f1 = open('fileInput', 'r')
f2 = open('fileInput'+".tmp", 'w')
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace('invalid', ' reviewed'+\t+'rd'))
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

`regex` can be an option but I'm not that good with it yet. Can someone help.

P.S. a,b and c's are variables.. I can't do an exact search on 'a','b','c'.

Comment: In what way does that code not do what you want?

Comment: Should it be `a b c reviewed\trd` or did you really mean `a b reviewed\trd`?

Comment: The output will be a b c reviewed rd.. I only want a b reviewed rd. c isn't constant

Comment: @mgilson I only want a\t\b\t\reviewed\rd.. not c..

Comment: Why do I have a negetive vote ?

Comment: @JonClements they are few lines that I don't care about..

Comment: I think that @JonClements wants to know if they're formatted the same as the other lines  (e.g. do they also have 4 columns?)

Comment: no they all aren't.. some of them are .. some of them aren't..

Comment: One final comment...Do you really want to create your temporary filename with quotation marks in it?  Or was that a typo?

Comment: oh no.. Its a typo.. I'll correct it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f1 = open('fileInput', 'r')
f2 = open('fileInput+".tmp"', 'w')
for line in f1:
    if line[:-1].endswith("invalid"):
        f2.write("\t".join(line.split("\t")[:2] + ["reviewed", "rd"]) + "\n")
    else:
        f2.write(line)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'\t\S+\tinvalid$')
with open('data') as fin:
    with open('output', 'w') as fout:
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(pattern.sub('\treviewd\trd', line))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('input.tab') as fin, open('output.tab', 'wb') as fout:
    tabin = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    tabout = csv.writer(fout, delimiter='\t')
    for row in tabin:
        if len(tabin) != 4:
            continue # or raise - whatever
        if row[-1] == 'invalid':
            tabout.writerow(row[:2] + ['reviewed', 'rd'])
```